# Adding draggable to table rows (with Kendo Grid)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, draggable, kendo-ui

I'm trying to add a draggable event on the rows from a table and I'm not getting what I should. It's a Kendo Grid that's creating the table structure. Eventually, I would like to drop the row on something that is not Kendo if possible.

#### HTML

```
<div id="Assets" style="width: 200px; float: left;" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget" tabindex="0">
    <ul>
        <div class="k-widget k-grid" id="Assets">
            <div class="k-grid-header">
                <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
                    <table cellspacing="0">
                        <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 240px">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="k-grid-content" style="height: 200px">
            <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 17px;">
                <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
                    <table cellspacing="0">
                        <colgroup><col style="width: 240px"></colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr data-role="draggable">
                                <th class="k-header" data-field="Id" data-title="Id" scope="col" style="display: none"><span class="k-link">Id</span></th>
                                <th class="k-header" data-field="Name" data-title="Name" scope="col"><span class="k-link">Name</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table cellspacing="0" class="k-focusable">
            <colgroup><col style="width: 240px"/></colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-uid="cc7fc98a-dc66-4a46-8d3a-b73d608cf32b">
                    <td style="display: none">1</td>
                    <td>A Commons</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="daf17bf4-52d3-43a4-acc0-034c7c53e5af">
                    <td style="display: none">2</td>
                    <td>A Chase</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-uid="6dbe2dec-e9ce-4640-8f61-f1ee4469a581">
                    <td style="display: none">4</td>
                    <td>Beacon</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="569798d6-433c-4dea-b56b-5833bab22058">
                    <td style="display: none">5</td>
                    <td>Seminole</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-uid="4639277c-97eb-43d0-9aa1-6402671474b5">
                    <td style="display: none">6</td>
                    <td>Commons</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="9ad1bf14-91bf-474f-9115-246c55c38eab">
                    <td style="display: none">3</td>
                    <td>Willows</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### JS

Here is my code trying to select the tr's I need:

```
$(".k-focusable > tbody > tr").kendoDraggable({
    hint: function(e) {
        item = $('<div class="k-grid k-widget" style="background-color: lightblue; color: black;"><table><tbody><tr>' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
        return item;
    },
});
```

I would prefer to do it a purely `jQuery` way:

```
$("<selector>").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    distance: 40,
    helper: 'clone',
    opacity: 0.8,
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 100,
    snap: 'div.node.expanded',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    stack: 'div.node',
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do when dropped but this should do the trick of moving a row from Kendo Grid to a droppable area **BUT** it does not actually remove the element from the `grid` so you should (or not?).

What I do when dropped is `clone` the element being moved and insert this `clone` in the target area.

HTML code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<table id="target" class="k-widget k-grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="k-header" colspan="2">Drop inside red area</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JavaScript Grid initialization:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data    : [
        {"ID": 1, "Nom": "John"},
        {"ID": 2, "Nom": "Jane"},
        {"ID": 3, "Nom": "Sam"},
        {"ID": 4, "Nom": "Charles"},
        {"ID": 5, "Nom": "Paul"},
        {"ID": 6, "Nom": "Josh"},
        {"ID": 7, "Nom": "Daniel"}
    ],
    pageSize: 8
});

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns   : [
        {field: "ID" },
        {field: "Nom"}
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

And finally the drag and drop:

```
$("tr", grid.tbody).kendoDraggable({
    hint: function (e) {
        item = $('<div class="k-grid k-widget" style="background-color: lightblue; color: black;"><table><tbody><tr>' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
        return item;
    }
});

$("#target").kendoDropTarget({
    drop: function (e) {
        e.dropTarget.append($(e.draggable.currentTarget).clone());
    }
});
```

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/WAw4Y/)

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite, meaning I'd like to drag from a kendo treeview onto a Angular-Kendo grid. Please help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811694/how-to-drag-items-from-an-angular-kendo-treeview-onto-a-grid